# Service Bus 1.1 installation getting failed on windows 2008 R2 SP1 core

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008-r2, servicebus

I am trying to install Windows azure pack: Service Bus 1.1 on Windows server 2008 R2 SP1 Core OS through Windows Platform Installer 5.0 (Offline installation) . I am using below link for installation  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalknotes/archive/2013/12/17/how-to-do-offline-install-of-service-bus.aspx 
,But i am facing following issue:

> Error message:
>
> Starting Installation
>
> Started downloading products...
>
> Started downloading: 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1'
>
> Downloaded: 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1'
>
> Install completed (Failure): 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1'
>   Service Bus_1_1 : Failed.
>
> Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been
>   tampered with Verifying successful installation...
>
> Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 False
>
> Install of Products: FAILURE

Please help and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check installation log, if log record looks like this, with 1639 error:

```
MSI (s) (20:5C) [14:22:31:139]: Product: Windows Fabric -- Installation failed.
MSI (s) (20:5C) [14:22:31:139]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Windows Fabric. Product Version: 1.0.960.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1639.
MSI (s) (20:5C) [14:22:31:141]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
```

In my case it was:
- My system account contained two words -- Name and Surname, like "Vasya Pupkin", so web platform installer saw only first "Vasya", so you need to rename system user to "VasyaPupkin" without space symbol, or install under different account.
- Also I've noticed error in PowerShell env path, so check System variables PSModulePath, and remove unnecessary - symbol (") (SQL server path contains error, \PowerShell\Modules")

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules";C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0\

Should be

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0\

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found so far was to edit the `webproductlist.xml` file directly:

search for `Service_Bus.msi` and replace the `<fileSize>` element with `<fileSize>7432</fileSize>` and above `<relativeInstallerURL>` add `<sha1>1c4bec246a78db77e92caec589c64ff7702f7aa8</sha1>`. (the sha1 was missing)

I assume that the signature is checked only on some Windows versions, because on Windows 8.1 the error does not appear.